# Angular ng-upload is not working for IE all versions

Tags: angularjs

angular ng-upload is not working for IE in all versions. Please suggest a work around.

code:

```
data-ng-upload="responseAction({content: content, ele: ele})"

responseAction: "&",

data-response-action="MIC.submitModal(PC.uploadComplete, content, '#uploadForm')"
```

This is not working as ng-upload is not supported by IE.